# Using typescript for create a node module, and import it as a dependency: Duplicate identifier (TS2300)

Tags: node.js, typescript, node-modules, tsd

I've created a project (named `data_model`) with some classes useful in my other projects. 
I’ve created a complete `gulpfile.js` which not only compiles my .ts into .js but create an unified **`.d.ts`** file which exports my symbols, the file is named **`data_model.d.ts`** and will be at the root of the project.

Now, I create a second project, let’s call it `my_cool_api` which defines in its dependencies a dependency to the git of `data_model`
Running `npm install`, the .js files are downloaded into my `node_modules`

Everything is fine and colorful. But the typings folder.

```
my_cool_api

 |—— package.json
 |—— …
 |—— app.ts 
 |—— node_modules
    |—— data_model
        |—— data_model.d.ts
        |—— index.js 
        |—— lib
            |—— my_class.js 
 |—— typings
    |—— tsd.d.ts
        |—— node
        |—— …
```

The problem here is the file **`data_model.d.ts`** because the very first lines of that file are going to make a reference to a typings folder which doesn’t exist. Let’s take a look

```
///<reference path=“typings/mongoose/mongoose.d.ts" />

declare module 'data_model' {
  import mongoose = require('mongoose');

  export class MyClass {
   …
  }
}
```

That’s the header of the .d.ts I’m generating right now. I had tried to duplicate typings folder (make it not to be ignorable by .npmignore would install that during npm install) which creates the following

```
 |—— package.json
 |—— …
 |—— app.ts 
 |—— node_modules
    |—— data_model
        |—— data_model.d.ts
        |—— typings <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< ADDED
            |—— tsd.d.ts
              |—— node
              |—— ...
        |—— index.js 
        |—— lib
            |—— my_class.js 
 |—— typings
    |—— tsd.d.ts
        |—— node
        |—— …
```

BUT that’s going to give me a hundred of "duplicated errors” (I guess because there are gonna be several node.d.ts files around). For example:

```
[16:44:33] [tsc] > /my_cool_api/typings/node/node.d.ts(1553,9): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'cleartext'.
```

---

My solution right now is copying any .d.ts file I found in node_modules to my typings folder and change the first lines (the references) of the copied files to my relative typings folder.

THERE SHOULD BE A WAY TO DO THIS. (I’ve tried too with tsd link command)
Any help would be extremely appreciated.

Comment: Yesterday I installed the last nightly build for Typescript 1.6, it has a nice solution for sharing code in npm packages. I'm on a phone,  so I can't help much more, check the bottom of this issue... Hopefully it helps:https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/247

Comment: This question needs a comprehensive answer. Say a developer is creating a typescript library called X with dependency A. Another developer wants to use library X but also wants to use dependency A. 5 months later, what is the solution? sure, https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Typings-for-npm-packages shows us how to allow X to be resolved, but using A outside will result in a complaint by typescript saying it's a "Duplicate identifier".  Is there a github repo with a similar example?

Answer (score 2):

> The problem here is the file data_model.d.ts because the very first lines of that file are going to make a reference to a typings folder which doesn’t exist.

Don't do this, avoid reference paths in general, but especially so for third-party typings. Just pass the `tsd.d.ts` to the TypeScript compiler directly (or reference it in the `tsconfig.json` if you have one). You will have to reinstall the typings used in your `data_model` in your `app` typings (at least any that are externally visible). Yes this sucks, but there's hope on the horizon in the form of [Typings](https://github.com/typings/typings).

Comment: So if you are using something like browserify, we need to pass every tsd.d.ts used in every typescript dependency to it?

Answer (score 1):

I want to share the solution I'm currently using to solve this problem. It's possible since `v0.10.8` of [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/) since it will search any `*.d.ts` file in your project - not just in the `typings` folder as it was before - and "compound" a global bunch of type definitions.

Let's say we have these projects:

1. **`my-module`** (our own module we want to include as dependency)
2. **`my-project`** (our project)
3. **`another-project`**
4. ...

**`my-module`** defines `my-module.d.ts` declaration file. Do not ignore it in the `.npmignore` so, once we import it as a dependency, npm will install not only the source but the definition file

**`my-project`** structure will be:

```
 |-- package.json
 |-- src
    |-- ...  
 |-- node_modules
    |-- my-module
       |-- my-module.d.ts
       |-- lib
          |-- ..
 |-- typigns
     |-- node.d.ts
     |-- ...
```

Visual Studio Code will recover, not only `node.d.ts` (and any file under typigns folder) but also `my-module.d.ts`.
Note that we *do* ignore (adding it in `my-module/.npmignore`) the typigns folder of our module, why? Because probably that would generate multiple `node.d.ts`, `express.d.ts`, etc files: one from the module and another from the project.

At this point I realized that, I was using a couple (~20) of `.d.ts` definition files among all my projects, so I decided the following:

First, I group every `*.d.ts` file (except those from my modules) in one folder, for example `~/workspace/typings-set`. There will be no repeated elements: just one `node.d.ts`, `express.d.ts`, etc definition file.
Next, all my typescript projects *create a symbolic link to that folder*

```
$> ln -s ~/workspace/typings-set/typings typings
```

(I call it `typigns` because convention)

Now, **`my-module`** and **`my-project`** has this structure

```
 my-module
 |-- package.json
 |-- src
    |-- ...  
 |-- node_modules
    |-- ...
 |-- typigns =====> ~/workspace/typings-set/typings

 my-project
 |-- package.json
 |-- src
    |-- ...  
 |-- node_modules
    |-- my-module
       |-- my-module.d.ts
       |-- lib
          |-- ..
 |-- typigns =====> ~/workspace/typings-set/typings

 typings-set
  |-- README.md
  |-- tsd.json
  |-- typigns
     |-- node.d.ts
     |-- express.d.ts
     |-- socket.io.d.ts
     |-- ...
```

Comment: Not a very good solution, what if: `Project Y => x@1.2`, and `Project Z => Project Y@1.0.0, x@1.3`?

Comment: Agree with you in theoretical level. Disagree in practice because the header file (I mean the .d.ts) does not change that "hard" between `1.1` and `1.2`. Problem between 2 major versions, but, again you're using ~20 modules and I consider this as a warning "Are you really interested in using sometimes `mongoose@2` and sometimes `mongoose@3`" Anyway I do know this is not the final solution... just a temporal way to go